# Eclipse not starting after Windows update

Tags: updates, eclipse

After OS Update (Win 10) Eclipse Neon isn't running anymore. When double-click Icon, message says `please check log file`. So, its content is:

```
!SESSION 2019-02-18 08:43:02.061 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_CH
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-02-18 08:43:02.762
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

I almost tried all tips found on stackoverflow and other Websites. I really Need help. Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse

Comment: What update did you install specifically?  Please provide the necessary information in the question body

Answer (score -1):

could solve this issue. easiest way was to reisntall everything. now it works again.